# Close WiFi iPhone

Tags: iphone, wireless-networking

Does anyone knows how to open/close the wifi from an app?
If not, how can the app direct the user to the wifi settings?

Comment: You cannot do it without the private API, but using private API is not allowed. So,to the most you can try it at your home, it will definitely work but Apple will reject such apps which use their private API's,against their norms:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This brief tutorial](http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/09/08/how-to-enable-or-disable-wifi-on-your-jailbroken-iphone-or-ipod-touch-with-one-tap/) will guide you through using Cydia on your iPhone to install WiFiToggle, an app that makes enabling and disabling WiFi a “one tap” affair.

**This requires jailbreaking you iPhone. SuperUser cannot be held responsible for any actions caused by this practise, nor the legality of it**